# In Pandas, how can I split a column based in a value from another column?

Tags: python, pandas, split, multiple-columns

I´d like to go from this dataframe structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
               'col2':['str_a1','str_a2','str_b1','str_b2','str_c1','str_c2']})

df
```

to this one

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1_1':['a','b','c'],
                'col2_1':['str_a1','str_b1','str_c1'],
                'col2_2':['str_a2','str_b2','str_c2']})
df2
```

Is there a way to accomplish this in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use, `assign` and `pivot` and `add_prefix`

```
s = df.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1)
df_out =  (df.assign(n=s).pivot('col1', 'n', 'col2').add_prefix('col2_')
             .reset_index())

Out[32]:
n col1  col2_1  col2_2
0    a  str_a1  str_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

---

Or `set_index` and `pivot` and `T`

```
s = df.groupby('col1').cumcount().add(1)
df_out = (df.set_index(s).pivot(columns='col1', values='col2')
            .rename(lambda x: f'col2_{x}').T.reset_index())

Out[75]:
  col1  col2_1  col2_2
0    a  str_a1  str_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked like a charm. I´d make just one observation: it is not necessary to include ```.add(1)``` when creating the data frame ```s```. I upvoted your answer and accepted it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try, using `set_index` with `groupby` and `cumcount` then reshape with `unstack` and flatten multiindex column header:

```
df_out = df.set_index(['col1', df.groupby('col1').cumcount() + 1]).unstack()
df_out.columns = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df_out.columns]
print(df_out.reset_index())
```

Output:

```
  col1  col2_1  col2_2
0    a  str_a1  str_a2
1    b  str_b1  str_b2
2    c  str_c1  str_c2
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked perfectly, although using more functions than Andy L´s answer. I upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

If your 'col1' is repeated same number of times then you can use numpy reshape like below to get the result

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['a','a','b','b','c','c'],
               'col2':['str_a1','str_a2','str_b1','str_b2','str_c1','str_c2']})

## 4 is square of number of repeates in this case 2*2
ar = df.values.reshape(-1, 4)
result = pd.DataFrame(np.c_[ar[:,0], ar[:,1::2]], columns=["col1_1", "col2_1", "col2_2"])
result
```